# ML/PWのログイン認証を実装したい

Tags: javascript, firebase

#### Mail/PW認証を追加したい

Firebaseを使用してWebのリアルタイムチャットを作成しています。
Firebaseが展開しているサンプルコード（[Friendly Chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0)）をベースにしています。
[サンプルコード](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/tree/master/web)では、Google認証が実装されているのですが、Mail/PW認証を追加したいと考えています。
公式で展開されているMail/PW認証のコードを追加したのですが、認証がうまくいきません。

公式の認証コード
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start?hl=ja

#### 発生している問題

上記リンク先のコードをもとに、下記の通り記載しているのですが、
Mail/PW認証のリンクに遷移できません。
具体的には、Webページ上のsignInボタンを押下してもポップアップが表示されず、Google認証もML/PW認証もできません。

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
function createUser(){
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
}

function signIn() {
  // TODO 1: Sign in Firebase with credential from the Google user.
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
  });
}

（省略）

var signInButtonElement = document.getElementById('sign-in');
var signOutButtonElement = document.getElementById('sign-out');
var signInSnackbarElement = document.getElementById('must-signin-snackbar');

// Saves message on form submit.
messageFormElement.addEventListener('submit', onMessageFormSubmit);
signOutButtonElement.addEventListener('click', signOut);
signInButtonElement.addEventListener('click', signIn);
```

```html
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color-text--white mdl-color--light-blue-700">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <h3><i class="material-icons">chat_bubble_outline</i> Snoopath</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="user-container">
        <div hidden id="user-pic"></div>
        <div hidden id="user-name"></div>
        <button hidden id="sign-out" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white">
          Sign-out
        </button>
        <button hidden id="sign-in" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white">
          <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>Sign-in with Google
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

#### 問題の発生した環境

・JaveScript
・Firebase

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/198986

Comment: 動作に利用しているFirebase Projectでメールパスワード認証を有効にしていますか？

Comment: @k2wanko コメントありがとうございます。Project側では有効にしています。